# ReCapatcha plugin joomla in external file

Tags: php, joomla, mootools, joomla3.0, recaptcha

i want to include the default captcha plugin in a form in external php file.
I included on the necessary for the joomla framefork (3.4.2).
This is what I inserted in the external file:

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','recaptcha');
```

and inside the form tag:

```
echo "<div id='recaptcha'></div>";
```

Well, the captcha is not displayed! no error in console or php. the div recaptcha is ever empty.
the plugin is activeted and works perfectly in registration page. 
I forced to include mootools libraries but nothing.
What i wrong?

Thanks,